# regex preg_replace - don't replace inside links

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

Ok here is my situation... I have installed a glossary add-on on my vBulletin forum. If a term is found on the forum, it will replace the term by a link to the glossary definition.

here is the regex code used by the add-on :

```
$findotherterms[] = "#\b$glossaryname\b(?=\s|[.,?!;:]\s)#i";
$replacelinkterms[] = "<span class=\"glossarycrosslinkimage\"><a href=\"$glossarypath/glossary.php?do=viewglossary&amp;term=$glossaryid\"' onmouseover=\"glossary_ajax_showTooltip('$glossarypath/glossary_crosslinking.php?do=crosslink&term=$glossaryid',this,true);return false\" onmouseout=\"glossary_ajax_hideTooltip()\"><b>$glossaryname&nbsp;</b></a></span>";
$replacelinkterms[] = "<a href=\"glossary.php?q=$glossaryname\">$glossaryname</a>";
$glossaryterm = preg_replace($findotherterms, $replacelinkterms, $glossaryterm, $vbulletin->options['vbglossary_crosslinking_limit']);
return $glossaryterm;
```

The problem is that if there is a link inside a forum post with an existing term, the add-on will create a link inside the link...

So let's say "test" is a glossary term and i have this forum post:

```
some forum post including <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> link
```

The addon will convert it to :

```
some forum post including <a href="http://www.<a href="glossary.php?q=test">test</a>.com"><a href="glossary.php?q=test">test</a> link
```

So, how can i modify this code to NOT replace anything if the string is found inside an existing link ?

Comment: simple answer: don't use [regexs on html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: this is not my script. i didn't write this add-on. i'm just trying to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

It's better to actually capture the bad strings which you don't want replaced with the good strings that you want replaced, and then simply apply some logic.

In this case the regex will:

- find all the anchor tags from open `<a ...>` to close `</a>`. Because this is first in the regex, it'll capture all the undesirable `test` strings which exist inside an anchor tag.
- find all the strings `test`, note this portion could be replaced with a `|` delimited list of all your glossary terms. This value is inserted into Capture Group 1.

`/<a\b(?=\s)(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?>.*?<\/a>|(test)`

[image]

Then the PHP logic selectively replaces the text based on if the capture group 1 was found.

## PHP Example

Live Example: http://ideone.com/jpcqSR

**Code**

```
    $string = 'some forum test post including <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> link';
    $regex = '/<a\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?> # get the entire tag
.*?<\/a>
|
(test)/imsx';

    $output = preg_replace_callback(
        $regex,
        function ($matches) {
            if (array_key_exists (1, $matches)) {
                return '<a href="glossary.php?q=' . $matches[1] . '">' . $matches[1] . '<\/a>';
            }
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $string
    );
    echo $output;
```

**Before Replacement**

`some forum test post including <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> link`

**After Replacement**

`some forum <a href="glossary.php?q=test">test<\/a> post including <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> link`